# CakePHP - quick and simple way to generate links to images?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm creating a photo gallery for my site, I plan to use the Lightbox. While using CakePHP can I automate the creation of lightbox related links to the images?

Is there any helper that can scan through my images directory and then generate links likes that:-

```
<a href="images/1.jpg" rel="lightbox[plants]" title=""><img src="images/1t.jpg alt="Plants: image 1 of 4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to save all the image details like "title, alt_tag_msg, image_path" into the database while uploading the image files. Then you can directly fetch the image details from that table and using foreach loop you can do it easily.

Comment: As far as I know there is no helper available to utilize this feature. But I'll try to give you a helper class in future that will give you a list of image links according to the directory passed as an argument to the method $this->FileList->getImageLinks($directory_name);